# GROUP_CONCAT return NULL if any value is NULL

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

How can I make `GROUPT_CONCAT` return `NULL` if any column is `NULL`?

Here is a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE gc (
  a INT(11) NOT NULL,
  b VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO gc (a, b) VALUES
(1, 'a'),
(1, 'b'),
(2, 'c'),
(2, NULL),
(3, 'e');
```

And my query:

```
SELECT a, GROUP_CONCAT(b)
FROM gc
GROUP BY a;
```

This is what I get:

```
a | GROUP_CONCAT(b)
--+----------------
1 | a,b
2 | c
3 | e
```

This is what I want:

```
a | GROUP_CONCAT(b)
--+----------------
1 | a,b
2 | NULL
3 | e
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In an `IF` expression check if any value is NULL in the group. I can think of a couple of ways of doing that:

1) Count the non-null values and compare it to the number of rows in the group:

```
SELECT a, IF(COUNT(b) = COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(b), NULL) AS bs
FROM gc
GROUP BY a
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f671b/5)

2) Count the number of null values using `SUM`:

```
SELECT a, IF(SUM(b IS NULL) = 0, GROUP_CONCAT(b), NULL) AS bs
FROM gc
GROUP BY a
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f671b/8)

Comment: Cool thanks :) I have a feeling this will perform terribly on a large data set though.

Comment: Just saw your update, do you know which one would perform better?

Comment: @Petah: I'd have to measure it to be sure. At a guess the second might be a bit faster, but I suspect that both will have reasonable performance. The expensive part is likely to be the `GROUP_CONCAT`.